# Any predefined Jenkins Job convert them to DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

My Jenkins Box contains hundreds of jobs and i want them to convert into DSL code is their predefined plugins or softwares to convert the existing jenkins job.

Any suggestions on these.

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

You could try this (currently active) project with quite a good coverage:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/xml-job-to-job-dsl/ aka https://github.com/jenkinsci/xml-job-to-job-dsl-plugin/.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any plugins or utility available to automatically generate Job DSL Code from Jenkins jobs

Answer (score 0):

There is a project for converting config XML to Job DSL scripts, but I do not know how  useful it is:

https://github.com/visualphoenix/jenkins-xml-to-jobdsl